# How can I prevent the hose in the toilet tank from popping out of the tubing?

Tags: repair, toilet

Unfortunately, I do not know the appropriate terminology but, there is a small hose that fits into a tube within a cylindrical container in the toilet tank.  When this occurs, I can see initially hear and, after removing the toilet tank cover see water running from the hose intermittently; this also seems to have an effect on the water level in the toilet bowl.

I can temporarily solve the issue by removing the tank cover and inserting the small hose back into the tube.  This works well for a while but, then the problem seems to reoccur.  I live in a rental which most recently replaced our old-fashioned toilets with smaller “energy efficient” toilets.  I cannot help but notice how flimsy the plastic parts are in the toilet tank.

Is there something that I could do to permanently stop the hose from popping out of the tube or is it necessary to call maintenance?

Comment: Tube gets stiff as it ages. When that happens, and problems start, I replace the old tube with same length of same ID Nalgene from the hardware store.

Answer (score 6):

That tube is supposed to be attached (often with a metal clip) to the overflow tube.

[image: Refill Tube Diagram]

It shouldn't just be inserted down into that larger diameter plastic tube (overflow tube), since as you've found, it will pop out again.

Comment: The problem here is that there is no "overflow tube". Kohler uses a "cannister" and the tube plugs into an opening at the top. The tube will eventually slip out of the top of the canister. See this for a pic: https://www.plumbingsupply.com/images/kohler-canister-flush-valve-1070282.jpg

Comment: @BJV are you asking a new question? This was answered 4y ago.

Comment: No, it is the same question. Just commenting that this answer will not work for this problem so if someone else trips over it like I did, they will know.

Answer (score 1):

The rod that the handle raises when flushing may be knocking the tube out. Flush with the lid off to find out. You can get a longer tube and reposition it so it doesn't get knocked out.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with a [hose clamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hose_clamp) of the right size, tighten it with the attached screw. If it's very small diameter, use a spring clamp instead.

As it's inside the water container, one of stainless steel should be used.

Comment: Or use a zip tie or tyrap

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your seal at the base of this drain tube will wear. Making it harder to push the handle down so when it finally releases it goes higher and knocks the full tube and cap off. Replace the bottom seal.

Answer (score -1):

I attached a small sponge under the lid that keep the tube from popping up due to the water pressure.

Comment: Just an FYI, but the sponge will eventually mildew and smell after a while...